# VNC software, which only gives access to certain applications?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, remote, remote-access

I would like to give a user in a competing company access to one of our computers via VNC or similar so that he can utilize one specific application. The VNC should function in such a way that if he tries to interact with a different application, it simply will not work. Does such software exist?

I know there are other, more proper ways to solve the same problem, but if such software exists, it seems like the easiest option to get started with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  It's called Windows Group Policy.  It can only be done if you are running a windows server as a domain controller.

Create a user in your domain, then apply a policy to it that only allows the user access to the one program.

There are plenty of resources on the web to teach you how to work with group policies.